# No blue envelope when using filters on Thunderbird

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, messaging-menu, messaging-tray

I'm having the following issue with Thunderbird 17.0.2 under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (fresh install and full updated):

When I receive a new e-mail on any inbox (no filters) everything is nice, sounds a notification, a notification appears on system tray and the envelope turns blue but when I receive a new e-mail into a filtered folder the envelope doesn't turn blue (sound and visual notifications keep working fine)

I addition:

- I have Messaging menu and unity launcher integration installed.
- I've checked "Showing in the messaging menu --> For messages in all folders" option.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly one of these bugs:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/893992

https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-messages/+bug/957922

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/841116